# How to get the vmware version through linux command-line without accessing the ESXi server?

Tags: command-line, vmware

I don't have access to the ESXi server. I don't have root access to any machine. Just a regular user. The current machine runs on VM and has Linux as its OS. Is there a way how to know the ESXi version?

I have tried the below. Is there any alternate faster way?

1. Find the hypervisor used

   ```
   systemd-detect-virt vmware
   ```
2. Since it is vmware, get more info on the vmware version

   ```
   vmware-checkvm -h
   ```

   VM's hw version is 4 VMware software version 6 (good)
3. Get the version info on vmware-toolbox-cmd

   ```
   vmware-toolbox-cmd -v
   11.0.5.17716 (build-15389592)
   ```
4. Find the ESX version based on the mapping at the [website](https://packages.vmware.com/tools/versions)
   11269 esx/6.7p02 16075168 11.0.5 15389592
   11269 esx/7.0    15843807 11.0.5 15389592

Since in Step 2 indicated version 6, and there are two entries for 15389592, I conclude that the ESX version will be ESX/6.7p02

What is the alternate faster way - without relying on https://packages.vmware.com/tools/versions ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following command

```
vmware-toolbox-cmd stat raw text session | grep version
```

I found it in the [comments section of another site](https://www.suse.com/c/how-to-know-what-esx-version-is-running-on-your-vm/).